# Tkinter Text widget - how to find out number of rows and columns?

Tags: python, text, tkinter, size

Is there any way to figure out number of rows and columns of a Text widget (provided the font used has fixed dimensions for all characters)? I'd like to load and display binary files in a Text widget, but the files can be quite large and in such case the widget uses enormous amounts of memory. So I want to load the data in a bytearray and then only display the appropriate part (which would be determined by slider position of a scrollbar), but for that I need to know how many lines of text can fit in the widget (I'm actually only interested in the number of lines since each line would contain a fixed number of characters in my case). How could this be achieved, please?

(Or if there's another solution to this particular problem, I'd be glad to hear about it.)

Answer (score 2):

So finally I've found a solution to my problem. The approximate number of lines that can be displayed in `Text` can be found by measuring the font height in pixels and dividing it by the height of `Text`. It is not absolutely accurate (I think the value is also affected by spacing between the lines and/or spacing at the beginning/end of the text or somethig like that) but I haven't dug into it more because just this simple solution works perfectly for my needs.

Here's a sample code, just in case someone needs to solve similar problem in the future. Just run it and then resize the window and you will see how the visible lines count will change.

```py
# Text widget lines (rows) count example - tested in Python 3.3.2
from tkinter import Text, font as f

class ExampleApp:
    def __init__(self, parent):
        font = f.Font(family="courier", size=12)
        self.line_height = font.metrics("linespace")
        self.text = Text(parent, width=70, height=20, font=font)
        self.text.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=Y)
        self.text.bind("<Configure>", self.linecount)

    def linecount(self, *args):
        num_lines = int(self.text.winfo_height() / self.line_height)
        self.text.delete(0.0, END)
        self.text.insert(0.0,
                         "Approximate number of visible lines: %d" % num_lines)

root = Tk()
root.title("Text widget line count example")
app = ExampleApp(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score -1):

Use the index method of the text widget like:

```
endline, endcolumn = text.index('end').split('.')
```

This function returns a tuple in the form line.charnumber.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I tried what you suggested, but it seems to work only if the widgets already contains the text. What I need is to know the number rows that can be displayed even before I load text into the Text widget...

Comment: Read the file first. Try >>>`with open('file.txt', 'r') as f:` >>>   `print len(f.readlines())` This will return the number of lines in the file.

Comment: I'm not sure if I explained my problem clearly enough... I don't need to know how many lines are in the text (in fact, the text will be binary data and I'd need to do some preprocessing including slicing the text into lines with a defined number of characters per line, but this is not very important here). What I need to know is how many lines of text can be displayed in a Text widget so that I can fill it with just enough text and change the text to be displayed in the widget when I move the scrollbar slider (the amount of displayed text will be constant).

Comment: This doesn't get the width of the widget, only the index of the trailing newline, which will always end in ".0"

Comment: This is correct. +1 
Returns the current column in the text widget and the current row, exactly as the asker requested.